# Ruby API for generating WAV files from frequency?

Tags: ruby, audio, wav

I'm looking for an API or any support in context of my problem. I want to have a WAV file of the same frequency whenever I pass any frequency value. I assume an API must exist for this conversion?

Thanks

Comment: Looking for replies if anyone have come across this api..

Comment: Ruby on Rails is a web framework, it doesn't contain any APIs for audio processing. I've edited your question to refer to Ruby instead.

Comment: @john..thanx..just did't saw dat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try warhammerkid's [ruby-audio](https://github.com/warhammerkid/ruby-audio), a fork of [the original](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/ruby-audio/) (which was slow, buggy, and unmaintained).